# Create jar for a maven project

Tags: java, maven, jar, package, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a project that will not have a main class. It is basically just to store the POJO. Now I created it as a maven project. I want to package it as a jar and add it into another project where these POJO will serve as models, I plan to add it as an external dependency jar.

I looked into the option of packaging using the below plugin in pom.xml

```
 <packaging>jar</packaging>
.
.
<plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <archive>
                  <manifest>
                    <mainClass>
                    </mainClass>
                  </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                  <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
.
.
```

Since I do not have a main clas, I kept the  tag empty. I tried simly building the project and didnt see any package getting created. A target folder was created with .class files but not a jar.
So I tried running **mvn package** from terminal. It failed with the below errors.

```
 Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) on project bart-etd-interface: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:2.22.1 (): Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.surefire:maven-surefire-common:jar:2.22.1: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.surefire:maven-surefire-common:pom:2.22.1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/maven-surefire-common/2.22.1/maven-surefire-common-2.22.1.pom. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required. -> [Help 1]
```

Supposing it was due to test cases being run, I changed the command to **mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true**
But it still failed with the same errors.
**I don't want to keep adding plugins if its not needed and want to keep them to a bare minimum.**
I am hoping on multiple sources, any guidance to understand this in a structured way will be good.
Thanks

Edit: I am able to see a jar created once I add the surefire plugin but still want to know why its needed if I am skipping test cases as the sources I am following do not mention its needed for just creating a jar.

Comment: If all you want is a JAR, then `maven-assembly-plugin` is not required.

Comment: just ```<packaging>jar</packaging>``` is sufficient for your requirement.

Comment: but just with <packaging> I build it again and I dont see the jar anywhere, can guide about the path where jar is created?